# Keeping elements on top using winapi

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I've written a little app in winapi which draws animated background like so:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    SelectObject(canvas, images[frame]);
    StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 640, 320, canvas, 0, 0, 64, 32,  SRCCOPY);

    break;

case WM_TIMER:
    SelectObject(canvas, images[frame]);
    StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 640, 320, canvas, 0, 0, 64, 32,  SRCCOPY);

    frame += 1;

    if (frame == sizeof(images)/sizeof(images[0]))
        frame = 0;

    break;
```

It works flawlessly but generates some problems when it comes to drawing other elements. I got some labels in the same window.

Right after first frame is drawn in `WM_PAINT` labels are still visible. When I replace canvas' (`HDC canvas = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc)`) image with second frame (in `WM_TIMER`), labels suddenly disappear - I guess they stay under that new layer that is drawn.

Is there any way to keep some elements always on top or bring them to top right after I redraw the bitmap?

Comment: The device context returned from [BeginPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362.aspx) has a properly set clipping region. I don't know, which device context you render to in your `WM_TIMER` handler. You should really put all your painting in `WM_PAINT`, and trigger a repaint from the timer by calling [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx). And please do show your **complete** code. We do not know, where your `hdc` is coming from, for example.

Comment: Yup, removed old one since it needed to be completely rebuilt.

Comment: You have to do better than this. You've already been told to put the painting in WM_PAINT and to do it properly. Don't try to learn like this. Read a good book. Petzold was how I learnt.

Comment: Well, thanks. It seems that I need to do some research on my own, but, for the love of god, last thing im going to do is to read a book about winapi in 2016!

Comment: The Windows API isn't going away any time soon, and knowing about it is certainly of lasting value. It doesn't matter whether you write a pure Windows API application, or are involved in an MFC/ATL project, or have to debug a managed Windows Forms application, or subscribe to the Windows Runtime: Knowing the Windows API will be of great value, or is even a mandatory prerequisite. I'd strongly recommend reading [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X). You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Maybe you're right guys, I'll give it a try in some spare time, thanks! Btw I found a solution - I needed to remove StretchBlt from WM_TIMER and use RedrawWindow everytime new bitmap was selected.

Comment: @MartinJames the previous question used a busy loop to do this; the person was told to use `WM_TIMER` (I think in an answer), hence this question

Comment: @solusipse the Internet has not eliminated the need for books; even though we read many books digitally now, they're still books. It may be outdated, but the Petzold book is still the way most people learned Windows API, and those who didn't have it around anyway just in case and have used it from time to time. (The sad reality is that there isn't a more recent book, let alone a good one; .net swept both Petzold and the market away...) You will find, though, that you'll still turn to books even in the Internet age for other APIs; even many languages's/libraries's docs are written like books!

Comment: @andlabs I'm aware of that, I just wanted to avoid reading that particular one as a person who uses Windows maybe once per week.